# Struggling to display this array because of this error

Tags: reactjs, firebase

i keep getting this error "Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop." I am not sure how to fix this error.

```
class ListCampaigns extends React.Component {
  state = { documents: [] };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.findDocuments();
  }   

  findDocuments = () => {
    db.collection("campaigns")
      .get()
      .then(querySnapshot => {
        var data = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
          data.push(doc.id);
        });
        this.setState({ documents: data });
        console.log(data);
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ol>
          {this.state.documents.map(document => (
            <li key={document.key}></li>
          ))}
        </ol>
        <Button onClick={this.findDocuments}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `documents` array is just an array of strings, so `document.key` would be `undefined`.

Just use the string as `key` instead. If you also want the id to be displayed in your view, you have to add it in the `li` element as well.

```
{this.state.documents.map(document => (
  <li key={document}>{document}</li>
))}
```

Comment: @MahmoodMapara Your `documents` state array is just an array of ids. What do you want to be displayed?

Comment: the ids in the array

Answer (score 0):

As in your code, the `state.documents` is an **array of id** **{**`data.push(doc.id)`**}**.

Therefore if for **key** of `<li>` you use document `{document.key}` **{**`<li key={document.key}></li>`**}** , it will not work because each element of state.document is not an object, its an integer value.

So, I tried to understand the requirement of yours and write a code for you.

In the below code you can also replace **{`<li key = {key}> {docId} </li>`}** with **{`<li key = {docId}> {docId} </li>`}**

```js
class ListCampaigns extends React.Component {
  state = {
    documents: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.findDocuments();
  }

  findDocuments = () => {
    db.collection("campaigns")
      .get()
      .then(querySnapshot => {
        var data = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
          data.push(doc.id);
        });
        this.setState({
          documents: data
        });
        console.log(data);
      });
  };

  render() {
    return ( <div>
      <ol> {
        this.state.documents.forEach((docId, key) => ( 
        <li key = {key}> {docId} </li>
        ))
      } </ol> 
      <Button onClick = {this.findDocuments} /> 
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

*NOTE:- The above written code is not run, so try to run it yourself and if any issue feel free to comment.*